# Отменить вытягивание с github

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

На github ветка куда периодически пушил с домашнего компа и с рабочего. В очередной раз на рабочем создал коммит и решил залить на github - отказал с перечнем возможных причин, попробовал через VS2019, она предложила Получить и Отправить - я согласился. В итоге у меня сейчас в проекте 90 ошибок с конфликтами, как я понял это из-за того, что туда залились старые изменения.

Последний мой удачный/нужный коммит "add API".
Как можно откатить на момент "Получить и Отправить"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/undoing-changes

Comment: Воспользовался командой git reset, количество конфликтов сократилось всего на 15, осталось  75

Comment: помогло git reset --hard